# Using C# .AcceptChanges() not saving data to Data Table in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I have a datagridview that I would like to make an identical copy of the current row, display it in the datagridview and save it to the data table.  I got everything working except .AcceptChanges() doesn't save the data to the table.  The row shows up on the datagridview just fine.  I don't know what I'm missing.

```
        DataRowView currentDataRowView = (DataRowView)sM_txdetailDataGridView.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
        DataRow row = currentDataRowView.Row;

        DataRow newRow = rDataSet1.SM_txdetail.NewRow();
        newRow.ItemArray = row.ItemArray.ToArray();
        newRow["Description"] = "New Row";  
        rDataSet1.SM_txdetail.Rows.Add(newRow);
        rDataSet1.SM_txdetail.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: Thats not what AcceptChanges does.  Each row has a RowState flag indicating its state (new, changed, deleted).  You've cleared all those so the Adapter wont know what to do to any row.  Invoke it *after* you have saved the changes to the db.

Comment: @Plutonix Actually the table adapter will do it for you when you call `Update` on the table adapter.

Comment: So I should call update on the TableAdapter?

Comment: I used .update instead of .acceptchanges and it worked properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what .AcceptChanges() does but when inserting a new row you should add it to the `DataTable` using a `SqlDataAdapter`. In this case I'm using a stored procedure to insert, but you can change it to your liking:

```
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow(); 

insertRecord = new SqlCommand(proc, connectString.UConnect);
insertRecord.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
//this collects the paramters, data type, and column length
for (int x = 0; x < columnName.Length; x++)
   insertRecord.Parameters.Add("@" + columnName[x], SqlDbType.VarChar, 0, param[x]).Value = value[x];
//this collects the rows to be added
for (int x = 0; x < columnName.Length; x++)
   dataRow[columnName[x]] = value[x];
dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
dataAdapter.InsertCommand = insertRecord;
dataAdapater.Update(dataTable);
```